# Showing LINQ Results on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I wish to show items that I have queried with LINQ on to the page.

I can't seem to find any simple examples!

I have my query, TOELINE is my database name

```
    // Get the data context for the GROUP database
    GroupDBDataContext db = new GroupDBDataContext();

    // Query the database
    var best_sellers = from bs in db.TOELINE
                       where bs.Company == "247HO001"
                       select bs;
```

How do I then within my `.aspx` page, loop through the results and insert them where I wish, I know that I can output using a GridView but, I just want to loop through each record and show the different fields wherever I wish.

So something like the below:

```
<div id="best_sellers">
<%
foreach (SingleRow in best_sellers)
{
    // Show each row, the Company and ProductName fields
    Response.Write("<div class=\"best_seller_row\">" + SingleRow["Company"] + " - " + SingleRow["ProductName"] + "</div>");
}
%>
</div>
```

I'm baffled that there aren't some simple examples like this.  It seems dead easy with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<% 
foreach (var SingleRow in best_sellers) 
{ 
    // Show each row, the Company and ProductName fields 
    Response.Write("<div class=\"best_seller_row\">" + SingleRow.Company + " - " + SingleRow.ProductName + "</div>"); 
} 
%>
```

You need to say what type the element in the `foreach` loop is, or use `var` to be lazy and let the compiler decide.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Sadly I'm receiving this error: `Compiler Error Message: CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'TOELINE'`